# Is there a better way to change the timeout in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, settimeout

Right Now I'm using this function to update some timeouts without having to pass the callbacks.

```
private _changeTimeout(timeout: NodeJS.Timeout, at: milliseconds): NodeJS.Timeout {
    // @ts-expect-error
    const timeout = setTimeout(timeout._onTimeout, at);
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    return timeout;
    }
```

Is there a better way, without having to use a private variable that forces me to use `// @ts-expect-error`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: Create your own wrapper for `setTimeout` so you don't have to use undocumented internal properties of the `Timeout` class. Using undocumented internal properties is always going to be a maintenance hazard.

Something vaguely like:

```typescript
class MyTimeout {
    private timeout: NodeJS.Timeout | null = null;
    constructor(
        private callback: (...args: any[]) => void,
        public ms: number,
        paused?: boolean,
    ) {
        if (!paused) {
            this.set();
        }
    }
    set(ms?: number) {
        if (typeof ms !== "undefined") {
            this.ms = ms;
        }
        this.timeout = setTimeout((...args) => {
            this.callback(...args);
            this.timeout = null;
        }, this.ms);
    }
    clear() {
        if (this.timeout) {
            clearTimeout(this.timeout);
            this.timeout = null;
        }
    }
    change(ms: number) {
        const running = this.isRunning();
        this.clear();
        this.ms = ms;
        if (running) {
            this.set(ms);
        }
    }
    get isRunning() {
        return this.timeout !== null;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```typescript
const t = new MyTimeout(() => {
    // ...
}, 1000);
// ...
t.change(2000);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeAVAlgWwKYHsCuAXaA3gFDSnQAOATsgG5i7rS5pZ4Bc0AcpgCboBSAZQB0KDDnwAfaADtsIENAC8s+SADcJMsEwyIuStmC5MlABRayZKrXqNgYBQCMwwANYczw72EoBzCA4wGXgAbQBdAEplAD5oGkxkHgAaSysKbCcQZGBoVEDVVCd0SlT06zBsCHQeAH4OJ0xMEHRgsrJo4nLSZAAzaDMAQnJK6p5OtO6mAAtkCGFq3DNIzSmAXzSNq0WzfPrC4soJqb6B3HhyLH786EGlFQAibBk+XuQZGofjqbJcWfmbip8qtultun85sJmOI8MpoIsxKwll4fP4INElHEuj9SBD5g5nK43CjhL4AitJuD-lCWBI4XIFCDymtkjNIfkKVYwaRQK1zN9yqczHiaTDcAKfrzfIiJMLqdCkZycWz5gq6SoGRpKaRudBdcBpsE-OhdgU5EUShKrCKpfymekRYC8hB7dbqTsOfbdcb8HMAErPGTvPzLQja6CUdC4bCUGQq0VI273VSMzZEDZEAD0megAFUIGBjWwiEQdHp8PgNegAO5wJC0vBmUOYsNWbPQbzCdOsgCMAAYBxT252iLhhAajSaAEwDvsrIA)

That might be slightly overkill, but you get the idea.